# Execute a method only when two seconds have elapsed from last execution time

Tags: python, time

I have a while loop which executes two methods. I want the functionB() to execute only EVERY 2 seconds.
I know there are solutions which can use the thread to use a timer to execute it every two seconds, but that is something that I DO NOT want to use. I want both methods to run on the MAIN thread.

```
def functionA():
   # Code goes here

def functionB():
   # Code goes here

while True:
        # Execute function A
        functionA() 

        # Periodically execute functionB every 2 seconds
        functionB()
```

I am not sure on how to calculate the difference between the last time it executed and the current time. I search online for a few examples but they seem to confuse me more.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the timestamp in seconds and check if 2 or more seconds have passed since the last execution.

```
import time    
def functionA():
   # Code goes here

def functionB():
   # Code goes here
lastExec = 0
while True:
        # Execute function A
        functionA() 

        now = time.time()
        if now - lastExec >= 2:
           # Periodically execute functionB every 2 seconds
           functionB()
           lastExec = now
```

Comment: I had a quick question. Is this in seconds? For some reason my code always seems to execute it. I put a breakpoint there and the time looks like a large number. Can you should me some output values of the now and lastExec?

Comment: `time.time()` returns the time in seconds, so if you wait 2 seconds, the value should be +2 higher :) Try to print `now` and `lastExec` when calling functionB and check if the difference is really 2.